# Como pegar o registro anterior e o próximo registro do meu banco

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou querendo pegar o registro anterior e próximo registro do meu banco, eu fiz de um jeito que deu até certo.

Para pegar o registro anterior fiz

```
$readPrev->readFull("SELECT * FROM ".TB_COURSES_CONTENTS." WHERE ordering < :orderingCont AND course = :course ORDER BY ordering DESC LIMIT 1", "orderingCont={$orderingCont}&course={$course}");
```

Agora para pegar o próximo registro

```
$readNext->readFull("SELECT * FROM ".TB_COURSES_CONTENTS." WHERE ordering > :ordering AND course = :course ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 1", "ordering={$ordering}&course={$course}");
```

Como pode se observar eu faço uma ordenação através do meu ordering. Minha dúvida é, eu tenho uma outra tabela de módulos, que também possui ordenagem, como consigo juntar tudo isso em um só para pegar o registro anterior e o próximo registro?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Se você quiser usar apenas o MySQL você pode dar uma olhada nas respostas deste link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql

Answer (score -1):

Supondo que seu metódo readFull retorna um array com os registros da query já ordenados, você pode navegar pelo array através do índice do array.

```
$dados = $readNext->readFull($sql);
```

Se você souber o registro que deseja manipular você usa o índice:

```
$primeiroObjeto = $dados[0];
$segundoObjeto = $dados[1];
```

No php existem algumas formas de retornar a posição de um elemento no array. Veja array_walk e array_filter

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).